# how to stop appium server through command line?

Tags: selenium, testing, automation, appium, appium-android

The command I'm using to start the Appium server:

```
node appium --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --session-override --no-reset --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium
```

How would I stop the server through command line?

Comment: Are you looking to do this manually or programmatically?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

**or**

Run `pkill -9 -f appium` in the Terminal.

If you're looking to do this programmatically, see http://discuss.appium.io/t/launching-and-stopping-appium-server-programmtically/700.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a lot of instances of appium running and don't want to stop them one at a time then try the following command it will close all of htem at once:

`/usr/bin/killall -KILL node`

run `ps -A | grep appium` to see how many processes are there and if there are too many then the command aobve comes to had.

Answer (score 0):

From a Windows Terminal the following will kill the Windows Process running Node

taskkill /F /IM node.exe